# how to overwrite ScrollView content in ios or change focus

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm beginner in ios ....
In One of my activity I have created Custom `scrollView` and on it I have created Some custom `textField` ..Now when we click on `textField` then my custom `tableView` opens but this table mixup with already existing `textField` ....If I add this table  on `UIView` then it does not scroll ......so how to overwrite on scroll view `textField` and scroll tabel with `textField`.....I Have Declared all `table delegates` and table appears properly but on scroll problem occur ....

```
scrollview=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,60,320,540)];
[scrollview setContentSize:CGSizeMake(800,1500)];

scrollview.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
scrollview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;

scrollview.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollview.delegate = self;
scrollview.directionalLockEnabled = YES;

scrollview.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;

scrollview.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = YES;

scrollview.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
scrollview.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
[self.view addSubview:scrollview];

AdviseDr=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,110,140,30)];
AdviseDr.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
AdviseDr.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
AdviseDr.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing; 
AdviseDr.delegate =self;
AdviseDr.tag=1;
[scrollview addSubview:AdviseDr];

table_AdviseDoctor=[[UITableView alloc]initwithframe:CGRectMake(150,200,170,200)style:UITableViewStylePlain];                                                        
table_AdviseDoctor.delegate=self;
table_AdviseDoctor.dataSource=self;
table_AdviseDoctor.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
table_AdviseDoctor.layer.borderColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
[self.view addSubview:table_AdviseDoctor];
table_AdviseDoctor.hidden=YES;
Medicalfacility=[[UITextField alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150,150,170,30)];
Medicalfacility.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
Medicalfacility.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleLine;
Medicalfacility.delegate =self;
Medicalfacility.tag=2;
[scrollview addSubview:Medicalfacility];
[Medicalfacility addTarget:self action:@selector(btnpress1:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidBegin];
```

Comment: [self.view addSubview:table_AdviseDoctor]; **instead of** [self.scrollview addsubView: table_AdviseDoctor]; . . . .

Comment: "table mixup with already existing textfields" means exactly what?

Answer (score 0):

The Better option is that when you clicked on `UITextField` at that time also hide your `UITextField` so your UITextField is not mixup with your `UITableView` and when You **remove/hide** your `UITableView` at that time your hidden `UITextField` again unHide( **give hidden = NO**).  Other wise there are many ways for solve your problem, i like this option so i suggest you.

Other Option is.

Take your UITableView in UIView, i hope that you have already know that UITableView have its own ScrollView so you not need to put in/over any scrollView.

And when you click on `UITextFiled` that are in `UIScrollView` at that time you also put restriction that user can not do with `UIScrollView` and `UITextField` also 
*(give userInteraction = NO)*. so also give *(give userInteraction = YES)* when your UITableView  is hide.

Comment: This is Right option but there are 7-8 textfield and 4-5 button which cover table length so ......I want another option .....

Comment: @rahul- check my other option :)

Answer (score 0):

UserInteraction is right for but You know when we write this [self.view addsubview:Table_AdviseDoctor]  then ....when we scroll already and then click on text field then my table open long below from required position then we write code UserInteraction.enable=No; then scroll not work this right but first scroll and then click on text filed then ..problem occur not right position .....